# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method ElementAt

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity

I'm using the method `Queryable.ElementAt(Int32)` to get a specific element of a query's result.

```cs
IQueryable<MyEntity> entities = db.MyEntities.Where(p => p.ForeignKey == id);

MyEntity entity = entities.ElementAt(i);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'MyEntity  ElementAt[MyEntity] (System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MyEntity], Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Are you happy to fetch all the "earlier" results? If so, either call `ToList()` to cache them, or `AsEnumerable()` to fetch them on each call, with the `AsEnumerable` just being a way to force the compiler to call `Enumerable.ElementAt` instead of `Queryable.ElementAt`.

There may be a better way (e.g. using Take or Skip) though - could you give more information about the bigger picture?

Answer (score 26):

You can simply mix `Skip` and `First` to do the trick:

```
mds.Skip(i).First()
```

Comment: @Steven: Any idea what the translation for that would be like compared with mds.Skip(i - 1).First()?

Comment: @Jon: Hopefully EF would generate the same SQL code for this, but my educated guess is that your `mds.Skip(i-1).First()` would produce more efficient SQL.  Good one!

Comment: I think you have to use `.Skip(i)` instead of `i-1` since `.ElementAt(i)` starts with 0. So the equivalent to `.ElementAt(0)` would be `.Skip(0).First()`. I'm almost three years late, though.

Comment: @RodrigoWaltenberg: You are absolutely right. I updated the answer.

Comment: Keep in mind that `Skip()` needs to work on an ordered dataset, so you might need to use `OrderBy(e => e.Attribute)` before using `Skip(i)`

Comment: Similarly, I came here in search of the Linq-to-Entities solution for `ElementAtOrDefault(...)`.  `Skip(…)` and `FirstOrDefault()` is so simple I wanted to kick myself - absolutely GENIUS - thank you!