# For loop with 20 items skip each time

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, c#-4.0

I would like to write a piece of for loop which would go through an existing list and take 20 items out of that list each time it iterates.

So something like this:

- If filteredList list contains let's say 68 items...
- First 3 loops would take 20 times each and then in last 4th iteration it would take the rest of the 8 items that are residing in the list...

I have written something like this:

```
var allResponses= new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < filteredList.Count(); i++)
{
    allResponses.Add(GetResponse(filteredList.Take(20).ToList()));
}
```

Where assuming filteredList is a list that contains 68 items. I figured that this is not a way to go because I don't want to loop to the collections size, but instead of 68 times, it should be 4 times and that I take 20 items out of the list each time... How could I do this?

Comment: Like a Linq "Batch" operator? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11427448/106159

Comment: @MatthewWatson it looks good, but unnecessarily it uses 2nd for loop which should only slow things down no ?

Comment: No, that's only using the second loop to process the items returned from the first loop - each item in the entire collection is only accessed once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are pretty close - just add a call to `Skip`, and divide `Count` by 20 with rounding up:

```
var allResponses= new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < (filteredList.Count+19) / 20; i++) {
    allResponses.Add(GetResponse(filteredList.Skip(i*20).Take(20).ToList()));
}
```

The "add 19, divide by 20" trick provides an idiomatic way of taking the "ceiling" of integer division, instead of the "floor".

**Edit:** Even better (Thanks to [Thomas Ayoub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2307070/thomas-ayoub))

```
var allResponses= new List<string>();
for (int i = 0 ; i < filteredList.Count ; i = i + 20) {
    allResponses.Add(GetResponse(filteredList.Skip(i).Take(20).ToList()));
}
```

Comment: Why not use `(int i = 0; i < filteredList.Count; i = i + 20)` and `Skip(i)`?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Thank you, that's indeed simpler and better.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight that will work even in the case of list having 68 items, where as the last batch would be 8 items ? P.S. I mean the 2nd case as well, from Thomas.. ?

Comment: @User987 you'll Skip 60 then take 20 which will end up to a take of 8, perfectly fine, dasblinkenlight: kudos to you

Comment: @User987 you can have a look at the [`Take(int)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,482) implementation

Comment: This will work fine as long as `filteredList` isn't a sequence that will be re-evaluated each time it's iterated (i.e. a List or Array would be fine). If the sequence has only linear access mechanics for the Skip() then of course this becomes an O(N^2) solution instead of an O(N) one. Just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 2):

You simply have to calculate the number of pages:

```
const in PAGE_SIZE = 20;
int pages = filteredList.Count() / PAGE_SIZE
            + (filteredList.Count() % PAGE_SIZE > 0 ? 1 : 0)
            ;
```

The last part makes sure that with 21, there will be added 1 page above the previously calculated page size (since 21/20 = 1).

Or, when using MoreLINQ, you could simply use a [`Batch`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13731796/993547) call.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a simple loop with `page` adding on `0`, `20`, `40`... iterations without *Linq* and complex modular operations:

```
int pageSize = 20;

List<String> page = null;

for (int i = 0; i < filteredList.Count; ++i) {
  // if page reach pageSize, add a new one 
  if (i % pageSize == 0) {
    page = new List<String>(pageSize);   

    allResponses.Add(page); 
  }

  page.Add(filteredList[i]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i needed to do same but i needed to skip 10 after each element so i wrote this simple code

```
List<Location2D> points = new List<Location2D>();
                points.ForEach(p =>
                {
                    points.AddRange(path.Skip((int)points.Count * 10).Take(1));
                });
                if (!points.Contains(path.LastOrDefault()))
                    points.Add(path.LastOrDefault());
```